# Geocoder not returning location name

Tags: java, android, google-maps

My code works just fine but the only time Geocoder returns the actual location's name is when it is something big and popular like an airport.  If I try to get location's name of some building in my city, it will return the building's number.  I don't understand why this happens.  Can I send an address to google maps and have it return the building's name?

Answer (score 0):

I'm just going to speculate on this one, but google maps doesn't know the name of every building, although it does know the address as each building is required to have an address but there is no requirement for a name. Once again, just a thought.

Comment: Thats the thing when I looked up the address on google map it have me the name of the building.